# Matlab Toolbar GUI custo icon

Tags: matlab-guide

I want to add a `?` icon on the toolbar of my gui that opens a new figure with some information about the tool that I've developed. I managed to implement it and when I push the icon, a new gui opens as I want it to be, but the `?` icon remains "pushed". I mean that when I click it, the icon changes color (to let me know that I'm clicking on it), opens the new figure but it remains with the changed color, instead return with the default color.

What command do I need to get it back to the default color? 
In the callback I just put it the name of the other gui,

```
function about_Clicked_Callback(hObject,eventdata,handles)
about;
```

Comment: How did you create the `?` icon? Did you use the GUIDE `Toolbar Editor`? If so, did you create a `Push Tool` or a `Togglke Tool`? Try setting a break point in the `about_Clicked_Callback` and check the `Type` property of the `hObject`.

Comment: Yes I used `Toolbar Editor` as `Toggle Tool`. Should I use a `Push Tool`?
Edit: yes, I should had. Solved, thanks